# How to get HWND of new process created by CreateProcess

Tags: c++builder, windows-process

i am developing an App for windows that will start some third party executable files such as cmd, paint, notepad etc using CreateProcess function. I want the functionality to hide and show the window of these EXE programs using HWND or suggest any other solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateProcess()` does not return the `HWND` of the new process so you will have to find it manually.  Use `EnumWindows()` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to find `HWNDs` whose process/thread IDs match the same IDs that `CreateProcess()` returns in the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` struct.  Once you have the `HWND`s, you can use `ShowWindow()` to show/hide them as needed.